# how to make a loop that writes to a file python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to save the currency rates I get from the yahoo finance API to a .txt file as a while loop while the other thread is reading it and writing a graph with it. For some reason it won't write to the file so the entire program won't work

```
def thread(spot=1):
    while spot >60:
        savedFile.write(str(currencies.get_rate()) + ',' + str(spot) + '\n')
        spot += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Where are you opening and closing your `savedFile`?

Comment: This looks like an infinite loop... if `spot>60` you keep just making it bigger

Comment: I'm opening it right before and closing right after the loop

Comment: @JohnLaRooy yeah that fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

While the data is in the buffer, you can't read it into the other thread. You should `flush` the file. The tells the OS to push the buffer to disk.

```
def thread(spot=1):
    while spot >60:
        savedFile.write(str(currencies.get_rate()) + ',' + str(spot) + '\n')
        savedFile.flush()
        spot += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving stricter limitations to the loop. If you want it to write until it drops below 60 then give a maximum number to write to the file. One way to do it would be with an if statement and use the same counter.